# MicroSip интеграция с C#

Tags: c#, c++, voip

Есть ли возможность, используя открытый исходный код MicroSip, добавить в него функцию звонка по кнопке из другой программы, написанной на C#? 
https://www.microsip.org/source Насколько я понял, MicroSip исходники на C++, к сожалению, им не владею. Чтобы начать копать, хочу просто узнать, есть ли смысл.
Может быть уже есть те, кто делал нечто подобное, буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Можете пояснить, что означает "добавить функцию звонка по кнопке из другой программы"?

Comment: Попробую. Допустим у нас есть некая программа на C#, которая выдает номера телефонов. Под этим номером телефона, допустим, у нас будет кнопка, при нажатии на которую, каким-то образом номер передается в microsip и оттуда уже производится набор (ну или как вариант, сразу стартовать набор после передачи номера).